# docker 1.9 registry API change

Tags: docker, repository, docker-compose

Is it possible to tell docker to use v1 repository. We use v1 for our images but docker 1.9.1 use v2 and i`m getting error:

"Error getting v2 registry: endpoint does not support v2 API"

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that there was 0% free space on the registry server.